# How to combine two python files using third python file which can also add some code to the same file?

Tags: python

I have two python files I want to make a program that can merge those files and show me the new file.

File 1

```py
def functiona(a):
    print("hi")
```

File 2

```py
def functionb(a):
    print("hi")
```

Combined file

```py
def function(a):
    print("hi")

def functionb(a):
    print("hi")

if __name__ = "__main__":
    functiona(4)
    functionb(5)
```

Comment: `from file[1,2] import function[a,b]`?

Comment: Do you just want to merge the files as if they were text files and add text at the bottom?

Comment: Where do the bottom 3 lines come from in the merged file? what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a new python file which contains the full code as in both previous files with some extra added code as the main function.

Comment: I had not tried this as I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Can variables and function names be the same? What happens if they can be the same? if not, this is a simple copy and append program. it seems Shadowfax already provided one.

Comment: I want such a method which lines all the imports together and files only consists of functions so there is no problem of variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
Put this in a file and use it from the console to combine the functions and output them in one file.

```
# arg 0: The path where the combined file will be created.
# args 1..inf: Paths to the files where your functions found.

import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as out_file:
    for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
        with open(sys.argv[i]) as in_file:
            for l in in_file.readlines():
                out_file.writelines(l)
            out_file.writelines("\n\n")

    # What ever you need to add at the end"
    additional_text = 'if __name__ = "__main__":\n\tfunctiona(4)\n\tfunctionb(5)'
    out_file.writelines(additional_text)
```